# error when running Get-AzManagementGroup PowerShell Command

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rbac

I am a global administrator and when I run the command Get-AzManagementGroup I get the following error:

> Get-AzManagementGroup : The client 'live.com#kellygarcia9@yahoo.co.uk'
>   with object id 'bd24ab44-e034-439e-8a02-756d1e3557a3' does not have
>   authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read' over scope
>   '/providers/Microsoft.Management' or the scope is invalid. If access
>   was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Get-AzManagementGroup
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzManagementGroup], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.ManagementGroups.GetAzureRmManagementGroup

Comment: this error also happens when you do not have any management groups ... after creating a management group and assigning an existing subscription into this new management group then the command will run OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get user access administrator role to manage management groups

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgnPA.png]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/overview#root-management-group-for-each-directory

Answer (score 1):

the error clearly indicates that you dont have permissions to perform the action. you'd need to grant yourself using account which has permissions to do that (or ask somebody to grant you those).

Here's the specific permission you need: `Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read`

Comment: how to grant that specific permission to the service account?

Comment: create a custom rbac role, only way to do that

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion :-)